# defaultUrl, loginUrl in ASP.NET web.config

Tags: asp.net

If I get following setting defined in web.config, and what's the behavior of entering the web site, says, www.abc.com?

Will I first go to default.aspx and then login.aspx? I get a problem which may be caused by this setting.

```
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" loginUrl="Login.aspx" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="120" />
```

Comment: Have you add authorization (allow/deny) markup in web.config?

Comment: Hi adatapost, yes I get some this in web.config

Answer (score 1):

The first page you will go is not relate to any of them.

It is defined as follows in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear />
<add value="Test.aspx" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Check this [page](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

LoginUrl defines what is the url of the login.

DefaultUrl defines where the authentication process will take you after login.

Basically user tries to access Default.aspx. IIS takes the request and search for the autentication cookie if this does not exist the LoginUrl is used and processed.

But, for this to happen (at least reach default.asp) you have to include enable anonymous access.

I hope it helps.