# Forms authentication keeps logging out after inactivity

Tags: asp.net, timeout, forms-authentication

When running locally, my site runs fine. However when on the live site, after around 10 seconds of inactivity I keep getting logged out.

My web config line for authentication looks like the following:

```
<forms name="RaiseFLAuthentication" loginUrl="home.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="/myPredictions.aspx" timeout="240" slidingExpiration="false"/>
```

I have also tried putting `<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>`but this hasn't worked either.

A second issue I am having is that although i have set the defaulturl to myPredictions.aspx, when I go to the url www.website.co.uk and log in, it does not redirect here, it stays as default url. Although again, running locally I have no problem.

Can anyone suggest why either of these things are happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my answers to your questions:

1) This one is a bit tricky because you mentioned it's working fine locally but try this (assuming you are using InProc session mode):

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="30" />
```

2) It seem like you are missing the tilde (~) in your defaultUrl attribute.

```
<forms name="RaiseFLAuthentication" loginUrl="home.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/myPredictions.aspx" timeout="240" slidingExpiration="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The time out is controlled by the [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx) element, the default is 20 minutes if a timeout is not specified, so if all you get is 10 seconds I would look elsewhere in your code for the cause of the problem.

With regard to your re-direct issue. This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106896/defaulturl-loginurl-in-asp-net-web-config).